# Post back issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK. Let me ask the question this way:
Generically, isn't the page cycle:

page_load

onclick and/or submit handlers

page_load.

If so, what should the values of the controls on the page be during the onclick/submit handlers? The values selected by the users, or the values from page_load?

Answer (score 2):

The page load event fires *before* the control events.  Therefore if you change values in the page load event, then those changes will overwrite any values selected by the user, and in the control events you will see the values you set in page load.

If you need to do some initialization in the page load event but only when someone comes to the page for the first time, you can use IsPostBack:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //do initialization that you only want to happen when someone
  //comes to the page for the first time
}
```

Here is a good [overview of the ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) with many more details.

Here is a simplified example sequence:

1. Browser requests the page
2. Page Load fires
3. Page renders and is sent to the browser
4. User does something on the page (clicks a button, changes a text box that is set to autopostback, etc)
5. Browser does a POST to the page
6. Page Load fires (again).  This time IsPostBack is True.  Also note, this is not the same "Page" object as it was in #2.  Each HTTP request is a completely new Page object.  For example, member variables will not be saved across requests.
7. Appropriate control events fire (click, text changed, etc)
8. Page renders and is sent back to the browser again

Comment: Maybe i phrased that wrong. Is it not true that the page load event fires every time the page loads? Even after any submit event handlers fire?  
IE:
1. User requests page (URL)
2. Web Server processes page firing Page_Load as part of that process.
3. User interacts with form on page, changing some values in controls.
4. User clicks some button or otherwise performs some action that submits the page back to the server.
5. Server processes page again (with user changes, etc.)
Now, doesn't the page_load event fire again? And, basically start the process all over?

Comment: Yes, every HTTP request (both the initial one and each postback caused by user action) cause the page load event to fire.  IsPostBack will tell let you distinguish between that first request and the subsequent postbacks if you want your behavior to be different.

Comment: ASP.NET has a big long list of events that fire and do specific things for each page request. Read all about it here: http://aspalliance.com/134

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you check if the page is a postback or not.

Consider the following example - a user of a system is given the opportunity to change their name on a webform. When the page loads, the users name is displayed on the page in a textbox. The user can then click a button to save their name.

In this example, lets assume that a user called "John Smith" has his username incorrectly stored as "John Jones". He then decides to change his username by typing in "John Smith" in the username field.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.txtName.Text = "John Jones";
}

protected void SaveDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string username = this.txtName.Text;
}
```

In this case, you would expect that the string username would now be set to "John Smith."
However, as the page loads again on a postback, it actually resets to "John Jones".

Therefore we must check if the page is a postback or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
    {
    this.txtName.Text = "John Jones";
    }
}
```

Now, the username string would be set to "John Smith" as the user intended.